Is my washing machine and sink drain vented properly?
I'm trying to figure out if a drain is vented properly. But first here's the backstory:
We have a washer in the basement and also a sink in another part of the basement. The washer had a standpipe and a P-trap:
 
None of this was supported by anything except that the P-trap was sitting on the floor, and there was a connection to the drain stack at the other end of the (upward-sloping) trap arm – but it was loose! I never paid any attention to this before and as far as I know it's been that way for 20 years, since we moved in.
In the course of removing the washing machine hose from the standpipe to clean it there was way too much leverage and a small movement I made cracked the joint into the P-trap, as shown in the above photo. So I rebuilt and replaced the whole thing. Here’s the new setup:

The trap arm and standpipe are now supported, and the trap arm has a downward slope of ¼” per foot (½” total) from the trap toward the drain. Although I couldn't make the whole thing with 2” pipe, I did make the standpipe with 2”, the rest is 1½“ as before.
The issue I'm concerned about, having done some more reading, is venting. Here is how the drain from the washer feeds into the main drain stack:

The point marked B on this photo is just three or four inches away from the point marked A on the photo above, and at the same level. The other drain pipe coming into that fitting from the right is from a sink in another part of the basement (that sink has like a 30° downward sloping trap arm, but that's a different problem).
So it seems to me from my very limited knowledge and reading like both of these drains should have vents, but I'm not clear whether venting elsewhere in the system will vent them as well, or if they need their own. I don't see any good way to actually vent to the outside from these locations.
The reason things are this way, right or wrong, is  almost certainly that they were installed by the previous owner, who knew how to do the basics of many trades but didn’t know the rules for some of them (we could have a whole conversation here about hidden junction boxes on the electrical side!). So for example I think he knew how to glue the pipe but not necessarily the rules for how it should run.
On the other hand I just looked at the drain piping in my kitchen, which was remodeled a few years ago. The work was done by a skilled licensed plumber with a great reputation, and it was inspected, and I don't see a vent for that drain anywhere either. The pipe goes through the floor into the basement where it is exposed and there's no connection anywhere that I can find to a vertical vent.
Can someone explain the venting rules and whether they indicate that the setup I have for the washer – and I guess also the basement sink – needs something different to  meet code, or not?
Thanks!

Very nice repair.  "That's not going anywhere." :)

Whether or not IPC is your adopted code, the IPC code is freely available online and quite readable if you want to know things. If IPC is your adopted code, so much the better - if not, be aware that IPC and UPC have differences in details, likewise for local codes not explicitly based on IPC or UPC. If the trap arm (from the trap exit to the stack) is 6 feet or less (since you used 1-1/2" pipe) at 1/4" per foot, it's vented via the stack, for IPC purposes. That possibly seems to be the case, though the entrance to the stack on another look at the picture is more dubious.

I tried to read my local code but it is 152 pages long and far too technical for me. It is a state code (MA) and I'm pretty sure it's based on UPC.

What you have there might be wet-vented.  Because the trap arm meets a much larger pipe so soon, and that pipe soon joins a main riser (in the dark) you might be receiving vent air from that.
Unfortunately, since you had an upward-sloping trap arm that you (nicely) corrected, you will now have better outflow of water, more likely to siphon the trap.  So the fact it "always worked" is of no value at all.   So you ought to ensure that either, the wet-venting is to code (I don't think so but not sure) or you put in a vent at the top of the stack where the cleanout is, and attach it to the main stack higher up.
Ask a new question, with just the last two photos and the question is whether a laundry machine and sink feeding into an unvented 3 inch vertical pipe that joins a vented one about two feet below is an acceptable arrangement for a wet vent.

Thanks! My overall attitude has been that it's not broken as far as I can tell, and it should work way better than that old setup with the upward sloping trap arm (right?). But if it's not strictly to code it would be about the 1000th thing in this house that isn't, so my goal is really to make sure there's no danger.
If it's not venting properly is the sign of that going to be just the stink of sewer gas in the laundry room? I can't smell a lot of stuff because of allergies but the rest of my family has no trouble noticing the slightest odor, so if that's the case we will detect it .

The issue about siphoning would be if the water going down the PVC fitting into the cast iron wye draws the water out of the trap, right? Can I check that by opening the trap cleanout after a load of wash to see if there's water remaining in there?
Yes that is a cast iron stack behind the PVC, sorry the lighting was bad. I can get a better picture of that if it's helpful. But I'm confused about how adding a vent here and tying it into the cast iron higher up would somehow make it compliant. Is the idea just that that vent would be coming off the top of the PVC fittings?

Hmmm, did some reading about wet venting. It seems like any gas is only going to vent upwards. I don't see how that's going to happen – the trap arm is short and has a slight down slope, but that PVC fitting that goes into the cast iron is steep (45°) and has a pretty good drop in it, so how would any trapped gas get through that? Or are we just assuming that the path of least resistance for sewer gas would be up through the roof and not into the laundry drain in the first place?

Venting isn't about releasing trapped gas.  Proper slope is about avoiding trapped gas.  Check!  Venting is about replacing water with air in the trap arm so it doesn't suck it in through the trap.  That is not dependent on gravity.   There are problems with the details of how this works, but with a 3" or 4" pipe servicing a 1-1/2" one from one appliance, a lot of those problems go away.

Thank you! I need to find a primer on this. I'm a retired science teacher and this stuff should make perfect sense, but I think I'm not following the fluid dynamics and the sources and flow of gas and water well enough. I'll go look for some videos  and diagrams that explain it.

Well, you know, high school science problems are the cliche used to describe problems and solutions divorced from real-world details.  There are a LOT of problems you have to avoid in building a drain system, and a lot of people confuse the many rules with which problems they solve.

I modified my answer significantly because earlier I did not account for your improved trap arm and its correct slope.  You ought to make sure the venting is correct.

OK thanks. I will ask the new question as suggested but kind of flat out for the next day or two so will do so after that. I think the reason the old trap arm sloped upward was purely because the joint to the tee was loose and the arm was able to rotate downward. Based on how plumbing and electrical were done here, I seriously doubt it was by design.

It appears that the piping isn’t vented, but I can’t make out the arrangement in the last photo. If this sketch accurately depicts the piping, it’s not vented (although it might still function properly).

The vent would need to be from the red arrow to be correct.

Thank you for taking the time to make the diagram. It is correct. The question that someone suggested and which I posted separately is whether the main drain line (the silver / grey in your diagram), which I'm sure is vented although I don't know where, counts as a wet vent. I have no idea if it would or not.

The main drain line would not be a wet vent in this arraignment because the branch rises vertically up. If the tee picking up the laundry and the sink were connected directly to the main line (and other conditions that cannot be confirmed from the provided photo), it would then act as a wet vent. If there is a vent on the drain going to the sink, that could act as a wet vent for the laundry.
